# Vertically center a div, then how to clean up input text values with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a div to be in the center (vertically and horizontally) of another one, but was only able to horizontally center it, not vertically. Would you please let me know how to do that in my code below?

The second part of the question is: I have been trying to use jQuery to reset the input text values of my form through "button1", but that is not working too, would you know why?

Thank you so much!

Current outcome (outer div in gray, inner div in yellow):
[image]

Code:
    
    
    
        
            Landing Page

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#button1").click(function () {
                    $('#inputFirstName').removeAttr('value');
                    $("#inputFirstName").val('');
                });
            });

        </script>

        <style>
            #formTable {
                border: 1px solid black;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            #outer {
                width: 100%;
                height: 500px;
                background-color: gray;
            }            

            #inner {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>

    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <div id="outer">  
            <div id="inner">

                <h:form class="signupform">

                    <p>Sign-up for more:</p>

                    <table id="formTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td>First Name:</td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="inputFirstName" value="#{visitor.firstName}"/></td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Last Name:</td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="inputLastName" value="#{visitor.lastName}"/></td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email:</td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="inputEmail" value="#{visitor.email}"/></td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>


                    <p><h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="#{visitor.registerVisitor()}"/>
                    <h:outputText id="outputText" value="#{visitor.result}"/></p>

                </h:form>

                <button id="button1">Empty the div element</button>

            </div>
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#button1").click(function () {
                    $('#inputFirstName').removeAttr('value');
                    $("#inputFirstName").val('');
                });
            });

        </script>

        <style>
            #formTable {
                border: 1px solid black;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            #outer {
                width: 100%;
                height: 500px;
                background-color: gray;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
            }            

            #inner {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>

    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <div id="outer">  
            <div id="inner">

                <h:form class="signupform">

                    <p>Sign-up for more:</p>

                    <table id="formTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td>First Name:</td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="inputFirstName" value="#{visitor.firstName}"/></td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Last Name:</td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="inputLastName" value="#{visitor.lastName}"/></td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email:</td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="inputEmail" value="#{visitor.email}"/></td> 
                        </tr>
                    </table>


                    <p><h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="#{visitor.registerVisitor()}"/>
                    <h:outputText id="outputText" value="#{visitor.result}"/></p>

                </h:form>

                <button id="button1">Empty the div element</button>

            </div>
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

You can use flex to achieve that:

First setup `display: flex` property then `align-items: center`

```
    #outer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: gray;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked I am electing your answer since you replied first.

Comment: Thanks. Here you have an example how to clear an input field. http://codepen.io/mikemoney/pen/OWEEGb

Comment: Thanks, but now it is really clearing even the submit button. Is there a way to only clear the ones I want? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Currently, the script clears all inputs. It iterates through all of them. If you want to clear only selected you need to do something like this $('#inputEmail').val(''). This will only clear e-mail input.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to center elements.
just set your position either relative to center the `inner` div from the `outer` div or set `position: absolute;` to center your `inner` div from the body.

Replace this your css with this one:

```
head,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
 #formTable {
     border: 1px solid black;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }
 #outer {
     width: 100%;
     height: 500px;
     background-color: gray;
     }            
 #inner {
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     background-color: yellow;

     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     position: relative;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     }
```

And for the jquery part use:

```
$('#inputFirstName').val('');
```

Comment: @user1060551 Check the jquery part, and don't forget the hit the green mark if your question is answered! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

http://jsbin.com/yazimovega/edit?html,output

The CSS vertically centering can be achieved any number of ways. This method works easy for your purposes:

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Then The child can be positioned against the parent.

For the JS, just use the following:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text")...
```

Then you can loop through the inputs and do what you wish.

Comment: How could I loop through the inputs?

Comment: I've updated this codepen with example how to iterate through multiple inputs and clear them all -> http://codepen.io/mikemoney/pen/OWEEGb

Comment: Thanks, but now it is really clearing even the submit button. Is there a way to only clear the ones I want? Thanks!

Comment: If you looked at the jsbin link I posted above, it handles how to loop through them all, in the forEach statement. If you stick to your search of input[type=text] it would not clear a submit button, which should be input[type=button]